# How do I get the data from the supabase to the flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

```
child: StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: Supabase.instance.client.from("todo").stream(
    primaryKey: [
      {"idx": 1},
    ],
  ),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data?.map((e) => Text(e["content"])).toList() ?? [],
    );
  }
);
```

| idx(primary key) | content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |

I'm trying to get content with idx of 1, but an error keeps occurring, in line 4 >>> {"idx": 1}.

So I wrote this code using chat-gpt, but still the error occurs.

How can I get content with idx of 1?

Comment: I don't know supabase at all but a quick google makes me think it simply needs to be `stream: Supabase.instance.client.from("todo").eq("idx", 1).stream()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `primaryKey` parameter, you just need to pass the list of primary key column names, in this case, just `['ids']`, so your code would look like:

```dart
child: StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: Supabase.instance.client.from("todo").stream(primaryKey: ['idx']),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data?.map((e) => Text(e["content"])).toList() ?? [],
    );
  }
);
```